# how to set initial zoom rate in aChartEngine in android?

Tags: android, achartengine

Recently I'm using aChartEngine library in android. When I set attributes on instance of `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`, I found there are only these methods regarding `zoom rate`

```
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(visible)
renderer.setZoomEnabled(enabled);
renderer.setZoomRate(rate);
```

What I want is setting the initial zoom rate for my line chart when it first appears in the screen. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean the visible area as you really don't care about the zoom rate on displaying.

You can modify the initial visible area using these APIs:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minX);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
```

Where `minX` and `maxX` will be the range of your data that defines the visible points on the X axis. There are similar methods for the Y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the initial visible area using these:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(mCurrentSeries.getMaxX());
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setYAxisMax(mCurrentSeries.getMaxY());
mChartView.repaint();  // this line is sometimes required, depending how you are implementing the above 4 lines
```